# Migration policy when question is better suited for another site, but the answers are not

Tags: discussion, migration

In my opinion, the question *[How to proven a programming function in math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299748/how-to-proven-a-programming-function-in-math/46310278)* is better suited for math.stackexchange, because, at the end of the question, the user is asking for a mathematical proof.

When a question is migrated, do answers get migrated along with it? (I do not know). If so, what happens to all the answers containing code snippets (or even pseudocode), because they certainly don't fit math.stackexchange.

To put it in another way: what is the migration policy when the question is not suited for the current site, but its answers are?

**EDIT**:

The term 'better suited' can be read as 'off-topic', this is my acceptation of the term.

I have received  feedback describing what should be generally done about *off-topic* questions. What I am asking is what to do about the combination of *off-topic* question plus received *on-topic* answers. Should we disregard the answers, and simply treat the question like any other off-topic question?

There are 3 possible resolutions to this, none of them looking quite right:

1. Keep the question; downside - the question is off-topic
2. Delete the question; downside - we loose the on-topic answers, which contain valuable content
3. Migrate the question to another site; downside - although the question will become on-topic, its answers will now be off-topic

**2nd edit**

As it was pointed out in the comments below, can an off-topic question actually receive on-topic answers? That is a nice philosophical question. But from a technical point of view, a stack overflow question can ask for two different things. I would describe this situation as an *aggregate question* being composed of *atomic questions*. If one atomic question is off-topic and the other is on topic, *in my opinion* this makes the aggregate question off-topic. However, good answers can be received for the on-topic atomic question. I think this is exactly the situation in the link posted above, when the user is asking for two things : an algorithm to maximize a formula (on-topic), and proof of correctness (off-topic)

Comment: Should be the same: close as off-topic.  OP reposts somewhere on-topic and SO question should be deleted, (somehow).

Comment: so, on S.O., the question will get deleted along with its existing answers

Comment: You can't migrate questions older than 60 days, so that question couldn't be migrated no matter what.

Comment: You are linking to a particular answer (Bob Jarvis's), not the question body. Is that intentional?

Comment: not at all, it was a mistake. As i said, i consider only the question to be off topic, not the answers

Comment: @Newtonfan01 moving my earlier comment up here for more visibility - could you clarify and maybe provide an example of an off-topic question with an on-topic answer.  That shouldn't be possible because of the question is off-topic, it means that it is outside the scope of Stack Overflow, which means that answers for that question couldn't be on-topic.

Comment: please check the link i provided .  That question is actually asking for 2 things: 1 - a formula, or an algorithm ,such as to maximize a parameter. It has received answers on this, and all are good. 2. It also asks for a proof of correctness, thus making the question off topic for a programming site, but on topic for a mathematics site

Comment: You made me think if indeed, one off-topic question can have on-topic answers. But technically speaking, one stack-overflow question can be composed out of two individual questions, one on-topic an the other off-topic, thus making the whole off-topic. However, good answers can be received for the on-topic part of the question

Comment: @Newtonfan01 algorithm questions are on topic.  You are getting back into the "better suited" vs "off-topic" discussion now.  Just because they ask for a proof doesn't immediately make an on-topic question off-topic.  If the request for a mathmatical proof makes you that uncomfortable, then it should be edited out to make it an on-topic question

Comment: I like this idea of removing only the off-topic parts, to make the question on-topic. I have extracted this as a separate answer, however,  I dislike the practice of accepting my own answer; Unfortunately, I could not edit your answer. Are you willing to append to your answer the part of my answer that is highlighted with gray?

Comment: @Newtonfan01 I will add it in my own words

Comment: ["Be a bit jealous of your site..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228628/165773)

Comment: a useful link! you can also mark this current question as a possible duplicate, if you consider appropriate.

Comment: that link is to another meta (MSE) meaning there is no way to close as duplicate

Comment: please post it as an answer. It can be easily skipped over in the comments list, and I think those answers are really valuable and indeed relevant for the current question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR;** 
To summarize - off-topic, vote to close and try to migrate if you are familiar with the scope of the target site.  On-topic, do nothing or at best leave a comment pointing out the existence of the other site. And if an off-topic or partially off-topic question can be edited to be made on-topic (without really changing the core question) then edit it to make it on-topic.

---

There is a huge difference between "better suited for another site" and "off-topic on the current site".

For questions that are off-topic on the current site, you should vote to close with the best close reason available.  This means that for questions that have direct migration paths from Stack Overflow, you can vote to migrate it (Math.SE is not on the list).  Otherwise you can vote to close it for the best option available.  If there isn't a direct migration path, you can us a custom Mod flag and explain where the question should be moved and why.  But you should still vote to close it because it is off-topic.

But for any migration, whether direct via the close voting or via a mod flag, there are a couple of guidelines:

- Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated by anyone so don't even bother trying.
- Only very high quality questions should be migrated.  A bad question asked on SO doesn't need moved to another site because the other site will probably have to close it again (why make 2 communities clean up the same bad question)
- If you aren't familiar with the scope of the site, don't migrate.  Just because something **looks** on-topic for another site doesn't mean it is.

But if the question is actually on-topic for Stack Overflow, but just "better suited" for another site - then you should do absolutely nothing.  **There is no reason to try to migrate on-topic questions.**  Of course you are free to comment to let the asker know that there is another site in which this question is on-topic and might give a different/better answer, but that is optional.

As you point out, there could be a 3rd case in which a question is mostly on-topic but it worded in such a way that asks for items that are off-topic.  These types of questions are most commonly found in external resource request questions, and are sometimes good on-topic questions.  But they have problems because instead of asking "How to do ____" the author asks "Where can I find a library that does ___".  These can easily be made into a good on-topic question simply by editing the question to remove the resource request and rephrase it as a "how do I accomplish this task" type question.

You example fits this scenario as well, as the algorithm question is on topic, but the request for a mathematical proof doesn't really fit the scope of the site.

Comment: I must emphasize that, when i called that question 'better suited for another site', I meant 'off-topic'; it was a gentle way of saying. In your answer, you treated 'off-topic' and 'better-suited' as two distinct cases. I doubt this is the case. Yes, theoretically it is possible, but in most cases, i believe that being 'better-suited' for another site is equivalent to being 'off-topic' for the current one.Why? because stack exchange sites are distinct by nature, their topics rarely overlap.

Comment: @Newtonfan01 that is hardly the case for a lot of sites.  Yes there are a few very specific sites that don't overlap with anything, but most of the technology sites overlap with at least 1 other site to some degree

Comment: In your answer, you have treated the case of "off-topic" question, describing what should be done. But what about off-topic question with received on-topic answers? Should we disregard the answers and simply treat it as an off-topic question, by voting to close it, with the possibility of loosing valuable answers? Migration is still not a good option, because on a new site, the question will become on-topic, but the answers will be off-topic; There are only 3 possibilities, none of them being equitable: keeping the question, deleting the question, migrating the question